# UITableView cell touch doesn't get called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've created my UITableView programmatically.

The delegate function works:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

but when I'm implementing

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

It just does' being called.

Having my UITableView being set not from the IB, should i set a property in my UITableVIew to allow cell touch ?

EDIT: added UITableView init:

```
-(void) showOptions {
    if (!_optionsTableView){
        float cellHeight = 44;
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, dropDown.frame.size.height, self.frame.size.width, cellHeight * _dropDownOptions.count);
        _optionsTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [self setViewBorder:_optionsTableView];
    }
    _optionsTableView.delegate = self;
    _optionsTableView.dataSource = self;
    [self addSubview:_optionsTableView];
    isOpen = YES;
}
```

this is the breakpoint. as you can see the delegate is register and it's from type of DropDownView - which inherit from UIView
[image]

Comment: Is the table view's delegate set?

Comment: The first two methods are the Data Source, not the Delegate.  Make sure you have both set.

Comment: @rmaddy it does.. wouldn't it crash if it wasn't ?

Comment: Why would it crash if the delegate wasn't set?

Comment: yeah my bed.. but it is set..

Comment: i've added my tableview creation

Comment: Try logging tableView.delegate inside numberOfRowsInSection to make sure your controller is the delegate.

Comment: Will try. Btw my delegate is UIView but it doesnt suppose to matter doesnt it?

Comment: @rdelmar please see the image i've added to the question.. the delegate is set and it's a UIView

Comment: @AsafNevo I also think that it has to do with delegates. Have you set **Table Delegate** and **Datasource** via the storyboard? If you'd post a sample project we'll spot the error right away.

Comment: How do you know that didSelectRowAtIndexPath isn't being called? Have you put a log in it to be sure?

Comment: @carlodurso its just a table im creating programatically so its not from a storyboard

Comment: @rdelmar i did. Its not being called